# WPF toolikit autocomplete do not works

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpftoolkit

I have a autocompleteox from wpf toolkit . 
I want the suggestion from database so i bind it a column of datatable which is populated from database. Using this code :

```
Public Function GetPatients() As DataTable
conn.Open()
If ds_all.Tables.Contains("patients") Then
   ds_all.Tables.Remove("patients")
End If
cmd = New OdbcCommand("select * from tbl_patients", conn)
Dim tble As New DataTable("patients")
ds_all.Tables.Add(tble)
da_all = New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
da_all.Fill(ds_all.Tables("patients"))
cmd.Dispose()
conn.Close()

Return ds_all.Tables("patients")
End Function
AutoCompleteBox1.itemssource= GetPatients().columns(0).tostring()
```

And the xaml is this :

```
<my1:AutoCompleteBox Height="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="316,30,0,0" Name="AutoCompleteBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" BorderThickness="2" IsDropDownOpen="True" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" FilterMode="StartsWith" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
</my1:AutoCompleteBox>
```

It does not work. Does not show any suggestion.

What can I do?

Comment: In normal XAML and MVVM, you would have a viewmodel property and bind your controls itemssource to it. I would expect an ItemSource to contain an IEnumerable of something, you assigned a string. That seems strange even for code behind.

Comment: @eranotzap  Yes this GetPatients().columns(0).tostring() works fine (i populates a datagrid with it)

Comment: does it return a collection of strings ?